# Class does not pass the self variables to functions inside of it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie programmer
I am defining this simple class but I receive the following error
I am not able to understand what im doing wrong

```
from PIL import Image
class PreProcessing(object):
    def __init__(self,NAME):
        super(PreProcessing,self).__init__()
        self.name = NAME
        self.newsize = 512
        PATH = '/home/alireza/Desktop/ssd'
        self.pathImage =  PATH + '/' + self.name + '.jpg'
        self.pathAnn = PATH + '/' + self.name + '.xml'



    def image_loader(self):
        print(self.pathImage )
```

When I call 
`NAME = '002498'`

`PreProcessing.image_loader(NAME)`

, i get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-5747710fa005> in <module>()
      3 sizee = [1, 3, 375, 500]
      4 # A= PreProcessing(NAME)
----> 5 PreProcessing.image_loader(NAME)

<ipython-input-37-5f788218f7e3> in image_loader(self)
     10 
     11     def image_loader(self):
---> 12         print(self.pathImage )

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pathImage'
```

Comment: You haven't created an instance of your class, but are calling it as though you are. Therefore, `NAME` is being passed as `self`.

Comment: To elaborate on what @kindall said, you want to do `PreProcessing(NAME).image_loader()`

Comment: And if you want to do more than just call `.image_loader()` you should bind that class instance to a name, eg `pp = PreProcessing(NAME); pp.image_loader(); print(pp.pathAnn)`

Comment: This seems like a totally unnecessary class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kindall said in his comment, you aren't making an instance of your class. It'll work if you set it up like this, creating a "hello" object of class PreProcessing():

```
from PIL import Image
class PreProcessing(object):
    def __init__(self,NAME):
        super(PreProcessing,self).__init__()
        self.name = NAME
        self.newsize = 512
        PATH = '/home/alireza/Desktop/ssd'
        self.pathImage =  PATH + '/' + self.name + '.jpg'
        self.pathAnn = PATH + '/' + self.name + '.xml'



    def image_loader(self):
        print(self.pathImage )

NAME = "12345"

hello = PreProcessing(NAME)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. Makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for fixing your answer. For the reasons for our "no code as images" policy please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). That applies to answers too.

Comment: Yikes, fixed again.

Comment: Why `hello` ? Maybe a more descriptive variable name, and an example of calling the target function`image_loader()` would be appropriate.